# Customize grid lines in d3 bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3fc

I am developing a two-way bar chart using d3. I want to add grid lines to the bar chart, how to customize those grid lines. I've used *d3fc* to draw the grid lines. It looks something like

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([0, width])

var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .rangeRound([0, height]).padding(0.5);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
    .ticks(8)
    .tickSize(0)
    .tickFormat(function(d){
        return d3.format('.00s')(Math.abs(d));   // Use Math.abs() to get the absolute value
    });

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
    .ticks(5)
    .tickSize(0);
//draw grid lines
const gridline = fc.annotationSvgGridline()
    .xScale(x)
    .yScale(y);
var svg = d3.select("#ageSexNotif").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

x.domain([-d3.max(data, function(d){
    return d.female
})*1.2,d3.max(data, function(d){
    return d.female
})*1.2])
y.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    return d.age;
}));

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .call(xAxis)
    .call(gridline);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis);
    // .call(gridline);

var barsRight = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")

barsRight.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(Math.min(0, d.female));
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(d.age);
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return Math.abs(x(d.female) - x(0));
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .delay(200)
    .style("margin-top", "10px")
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
    .attr("fill", "#F293C9")
    .attr("text", "label");

barsRight.append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    //y position of the label is halfway down the bar
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(d.age) + y.bandwidth()- 6;
    })
    //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(d.female) + 10;
    })
    .text(function (d) {
        return (d.female/1000)+'k';
    })
    .style("font-family", "Source Sans Pro")
    .style("font-size", "14px")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("fill", "#F293C9");  


var barsLeft = svg.selectAll(".bar2")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("g")

barsLeft.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar2")
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(Math.min(0, -d.male));
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(d.age);
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return Math.abs(x(-d.male) - x(0));
    })
    .transition()
    .duration(1500)
    .delay(200)
    .style("margin-top", "10px")
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
    .attr("fill", "#4880FF");

barsLeft.append("text")
    .attr("class", "label")
    .style("font-family", "Source Sans Pro")
    .style("font-size", "14px")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .attr("fill","#4880FF")
    //y position of the label is halfway down the bar
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(d.age) + y.bandwidth()- 6;
    })
    //x position is 3 pixels to the right of the bar
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(-d.male) - 40;
    })
    .text(function (d) {
        return (d.male/1000)+'k';
    });
```

The result of my chart is

[image]

My chart should look like this

[image]

How to join the edges in x-axis and highlight the base axis as shown in the image? Any help for customizing the grid lines is appreciated.
Link to my example [link](https://codepen.io/wittybutterfly/pen/yLNaoJN)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a working example?

Comment: I've added a link to my example in my question @ksav

Comment: I can't see any gridlines in the example.

Comment: @ksav Actually d3fc is not working in codepen but I’ve commented the code for gridlines. You can refer it.

Answer (score 1):

You can add class name to your grid lines using `attr('class', 'class-name')`, and add your effect by CSS.

Comment: I've tried but it doesn't work. Can we do without using CSS? @Daniel

Comment: @Max Maybe you want to try `opacity`  attribute in d3.js.

Answer (score 1):

I've made some changes to your pen that you can see [here](https://codepen.io/oliverforeman/pen/ZEGJdZe).

The main changes:

> join the edges in x-axis

If you remove the `*1.2` multiplier from the domains and add `.nice()` then the x-axis will be squared off with the gridlines.

```
var x = d3.scaleLinear()
   .rangeRound([0, width])
   .domain([-d3.max(data, d => d.female), d3.max(data, d => d.female)])
   .nice();
```

> highlight the base axis

We can do this using an annotation line from d3fc.

```
const line = fc.annotationSvgLine()
  .xScale(x)
  .yScale(y)
  .orient('vertical')
  .label('')
  .decorate(selection => {
    selection.select('line')
      .attr('stroke', 'black'); 
  });
svg.datum([0]).call(line);
```

Here we are creating an annotation line using our scales. We set the line to be vertical and we remove the default label by replacing it with an empty string. After that we use the `decorate` function to colour the line black.

> customizing the gridlines

We can control the opacity of the gridlines using a `decorate` function.

```
const opacityDecorate = selection => {
  selection.attr('opacity', 0.2);
};

const gridline = fc.annotationSvgGridline()
          .xScale(x)
          .yScale(y)
          .xDecorate(opacityDecorate)
          .yDecorate(opacityDecorate);
```

Here we are using a decorate function to set the opacity for the both the horizontal and vertical gridlines. Alternatively you could also use different decorate functions to style the horizontal and vertical lines differently.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Great stuff. Thanks! @Oliver